# Can i change my wireless router speed?

Tags: wireless-router

I have a very simple wireless router (without a lot of settings to change). I want to limit the speed for the devices that connect directly to my router via WiFi -- so that my PC which is connected to the router directly via network cable can get the best speed.

What can i do ?

Comment: What is the router model number?

Comment: even the cheapest and simplest tp-link have quality of service. Changing that should do what you want. But in order to really help you, please edit your question and add the router model too.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a basic router without a lot of settings, there is likely not much you can do without installing a more feature-rich firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato).

You can try limiting all WiFi connections to 802.11a or 802.11b.  Those are much slower protocols.  You can also try disabling 802.11n and 802.11ac, which are comparatively fast protocols.